# How to add property to a file when sending it over AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application where I am uploading picture files in an application.

The code for this:

```
            var files = $(".uploadFile").data("files");

            $.each(files, function (key, value) {
                data.append('file', value);
            })

            $('.userForm *').filter(':input').each(function (index, value) {
                data.append(value.id, $("#" + value.id).val());
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Customer/AddCustomer",
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                // logic  
                 $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
                },
                error: function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
                   // logic
                    $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
                }
            });
```

Server code:

```
   public string AddCustomer(HttpPostedFileBase file, Customer customer)
    {

        // add customer and return to edit view
        return partialView("customerEdit");
    }
```

I am trying to figure out how i can add a property to each file that I send? 
for example for every file that i add I create a list which I append to the DOM. 
In this list there is a checkbox next to each file which indicates if this file(picture) should be the profile picture or not.

How do I append a boelan property to each file?

Comment: You can use `data.append('key','value')` to just append more data to the FormData object, for instance the filename as a key, and a boolean as the value.

Comment: I will try that but I am worried  how will I be able to recive it? I am accepting a model as a second paramater that has specific properties. As I said I will try it but I I have some small doubts

Comment: You have to build your backend to receive the data you're sending, how else would it work ?

Comment: Well I can't build the backend model to have the same name as the picturefile now can I? this is to be dynamic.

Comment: Why not? And haven't you heard of concatenation, for instance `data.append('is_profile'+file.name, true)`

Comment: Hmmm, Sorry I approached it from a diffirent angle, I thought that you ment that i name the property to the exact name as the picture i was trying to upload. I will give it a go, could you please present this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @adeneo my brain got a jump start.

I had to retrhink my strategy here since I did not want to send the extra paramaters as a concatinated string.

I did the following:

In my first post I sent the file and the customer data. I saved the customer in the DB and for the file i stored it in tempdata in order to be able to access it in my second post where i would be savinng the file to the db with desiered extra paramaters.

script:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Customer/AddCustomer",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (data) {

                        // "Pictures" is an array that contains objects with all the file names and other properties.
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Customer/AddCustomerPictures",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: JSON.stringify({ pictureFiles: Pictures}),
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            success: function(data) {

                                //logic
                            }
                        });

                        //logic
                    },
                    error: function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
                   //logic

                    }
                });
```

server code, NOTE entire soloution not included:

```
    public ActionResult AddCustomer(CustomerM customer)
    {

       var Id =  _iScissorFingersManager.AddCustomer(customer.FirstName, customer.LastName, customer.Email,customer.PhoenNumber);

        if (Request.Files.Count != 0)
        {
            TempData["files"] = Request.Files;
            TempData["Id"] = Id;
        }
        // add customer and return to edit view

        return PartialView("CustomerEdit", customer);

    }

    public ActionResult AddCustomerPictures(List<PictureFiles> pictureFiles)
    {
        var files = (HttpFileCollectionBase)TempData["files"];
        var id = (long) TempData["Id"];

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var p in pictureFiles)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase hpf = files[i];
                   p.Name == files[i].FileName && p.IsProfile ? _iScissorFingersManager.UploadCustomerPictures(hpf.InputStream, hpf.ContentType, id, true), _iScissorFingersManager.UploadCustomerPictures(hpf.InputStream, hpf.ContentType, id);

                }
            }

        }

        return PartialView("CustomerProfileImage");
    }
```